# Create complex Recyclerview with horizontal tab breadcrumb style navigation where tabs navigate to section heads, and vice versa

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tabs, android-scrollable-tabs

I want to create a complex layout that will contain a toolbar with tabs that will scroll to a category in a list; and that will also respond to the scroll events of the list; so when the user scrolls to a new section (that is to say the category header item for that section is at the top of the list).

The UI will look something like this -->
[image: Category Selector Toolbar]

Usually the fragment items are viewpager; and selecting different tabs moves the ViewPager pages.  However in this implementation it will instead smooth scroll the list to the associated category header.

I've been looking for a sample of this and have not found it yet; although it does not seem like an obscure scenario.